# HTML form button not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, button

I'm building an alarm clock with HTML and JavaScript.

I have a function that plays a song `playSound(soundfile)`, and another function that calls the `playSound` function at a given time `Acordar(h, m)`. Both of these are working fine on their own.

I also have a form where I input an hour and a minute and when I press the save button it calls  `Acordar` with the hour and minute given.

The problem is, that when I call `Acordar` in this way, the sound plays ***immediately*** (it does not wait the requested amount of time before playing the sound). However, as I previously mentioned, both functions work fine on their own.

Here is my code:

The `playSound` function:

```
function playSound(soundfile) {
    document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= "<embed 
src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
```

The `Acordar` function:

```
function Acordar(h, m) {
    var now = new Date();
    var espera = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), h, m, 0, 0) - now;
    if (espera < 0) {
        espera += 86400000;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML="<embed src=\""+'starwars.mp3'+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
        }, espera);
}
```

And here is my HTML form:

```
<div class="defTime" id="defTime">
<label id="hora" for="hora"></label>
<select size="1" id="hora" name="hora">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="19">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
</select>
<label for="minuto"></label>
<select size="1" id="minuto" name="minuto">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
</select>

<button id="save" type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent" class="save" onclick="Acordar(hora.value, minuto.value)"><img src="save.png" width="50" height="50" alt="submit"  />
```

Comment: Why are you inserting an `embed` tag rather than using the HTML5 audio API?

Comment: @Toastrackenigma as I said Im not a very skilled html programmer :) I will take a look at that, maybe it solves my problem, thank you :)

Comment: It won't solve your problem in this scenario, *but* `embed` is designed for adding contents from plug-ins to your page - you don't need to use it for audio as there is both an `audio` tag and JavaScript API for audio. I would recommend that you look into them (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)), as they also allow you more control when playing back audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems & Solutions

Firstly, you need to remove the `id` of `hora` from your first `<label>` for anything to work. An `id` is a unique identifier, and it is thus required that you only use the same `id` once on any given page.

---

You can't access HTML elements as you do in the form.

To get the value of the select with the ID of `hora`, you use `hora.value`, whereas instead you should use `document.getElementById("hora").value`.

The syntax that you have used is what would be used if you were trying to call a method on a variable. However, in this scenario, the variable does not exist.

It **would** work if you had declared variables in your JavaScript code (after everything has loaded).

```
var hora;
var minuto;
window.onload = function() {
    hora = document.getElementById("hora");
    minuto = document.getElementById("minuto");
}
```

Or if you simply used:

```
<button id="save" type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent" class="save" onclick="Acordar(document.getElementById("hora").value, document.getElementById("minuto").value)"><img src="save.png" width="50" height="50" alt="submit"  />
```

### So, why did the sound play instantly?

The variables `hora` and `minuto` were not defined, and you tried to access them. This returns a value of `undefined` in JavaScript.

When you try to use `undefined` in a context where you would require a number, it converts it into `0`.

So, you called `Acordar` with two values of undefined, which both became `0`, so it ran the function in `0` hours and `0` minutes, and thus it looked as if it were called instantly.

Comment: You can use a field name/id for accessing its value on event functions, maybe is not the best way but is legal, at least within a form. The undefined was because the label had also the "hora" id and labels doesn't have a value property (if you tried the code only the hour was undefined, but the minute was defined). In fact, if you don't change the id's but move the definition of the label after the select it works because getElementById() now returns the select (when two elements have the same id it seems to return the first one).

Comment: Thanks ! Solved my problem and I actually learned some stuff ! Cheers :)

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez Well, I did not know that - I thought `document.getElementById()` was always needed! You learn something new every day!

Comment: @Toastrackenigma I'd use `document.getElementById()` too, but using the fileld name (yes, name, not id!) was the way to access form fields values at the start of the century...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the hour value you are passing is `undefined` because you have two elements with same `id`. **`id`s must be unique**.

Change or remove your `id` attribue from :
`<label id="hora" for="hora"></label>`

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

1. change this line from

   ```
   <label id="label" for="hora"></label>
   ```

to

```
    <label id="hora-label" for="hora"></label>
```

Reason: IDs must be unique on the page.

2. Change this line from:

   ```
   document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
   ```

to:

```
    document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = "<embed src=\""+ soundfile +"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
```

To solve for a syntax error.

3. Change this HTML from:

   ```
   <button id="save" type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent" class="save" onclick="Acordar(hora.value, minuto.value)"><img src="save.png" width="50" height="50" alt="submit"  />
   ```

to:

```
    <button id="save" type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent" class="save" onclick="Acordar()"><img src="save.png" width="50" height="50" alt="submit"  />
```

The syntax for accessing the inputs is incorrect, and the inputs can be accessed at the function itself, like so:

```
    function Acordar() {
      var sH = document.getElementById("hora");
      var sM = document.getElementById("minuto");
      var nH = Number(sH.options[sH.selectedIndex].text);
      var nM = Number(sM.options[sM.selectedIndex].text);
      var now = new Date();
      var espera = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), nH, nM, 0, 0) - now;

      if (espera < 0) {
        espera += 86400000;
      }

      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML="<embed src=\""+'starwars.mp3'+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
      }, espera);
    }
```

Comment: The syntax for accessing the values of the fields maybe is old, but IS correct, at least when used within a form. Your option is also correct but is tied to those fields, in its original form is reusable.